# Javascript Countdown Timer goes too fast even with boolean switch

Tags: javascript

I have the following countdown function in javascript:

```
countdownTimer() {
            //  exit method if it is active
            if(this.isCountdownActive == true){
                return;
            }
            // first time set true
            this.isCountdownActive = true

            this.countdown = 10


            // Define the work to be done
            var doWork = () => {
                if(this.countdown <= 0) {
                    ticker.stop();
                    this.countdown = 10
                    this.isCountdownActive = false
                    if (this.thisUser.captain) {
                        Store.submitTurnEnd();
                    }

                }

                this.countdown -= 1;
            };

            // Define what to do if something goes wrong
            var doError = function() {
                console.warn('The drift exceeded the interval.');
            };

            // (The third argument is optional)
            var ticker = new Util.AdjustingInterval(doWork, 1000, doError);

            ticker.start()
        },
```

**Here is the adjusting interval function**

```
function AdjustingInterval(workFunc, interval, errorFunc) {
    var that = this;
    var expected, timeout;
    this.interval = interval;

    this.start = function() {
        expected = Date.now() + this.interval;
        timeout = setTimeout(step, this.interval);
    }

    this.stop = function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    function step() {
        var drift = Date.now() - expected;
        if (drift > that.interval) {
            // You could have some default stuff here too...
            if (errorFunc) errorFunc();
        }
        workFunc();
        expected += that.interval;
        timeout = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, that.interval-drift));
    }
}
```

I believe this should work, however the timer still runs too fast occasionally and doesn't reset correctly. I would say 75% of the time it works fine, but after I click it gets "jumpy" and goes too fast. Also, the timer doesn't stop correctly. So that it cycles continuously.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the last timeout = setTimeout() function has problem...as drift approaches this.interval, the step function is called very quickly again and again

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the ms to however precise you want

```js
const span = document.getElementById("t");
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours()+1); // demo time
let tId = setInterval(() => span.innerText = new Date(d.getTime()-new Date().getTime()).toLocaleTimeString(),100)
```

```html
<span id="t"></span>
```